# Create one line function in zsh

Tags: function, shell, zsh

I want to crop several images using my terminal. For this purpose I tried to write this one-line function.

```
function crop_function { convert "$1 -crop 1048x909+436+78 $1" }
```

But if I write `crop_function test.png` The help page of convert pops up.
If I write:

```
function crop_function { echo convert "$1 -crop 1048x909+436+78 $1" }
convert_function test.png
```

The output is correctly:

```
convert test.png -crop 1048x909+436+78 test.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

===============EDIT================

The reason it did not work was the escaping.
This one does work:

```
function crop_function { convert $1 -crop 1048x909+436+78 $1 }
```

I have not understood why, because the function with echo correctly substitutes the variables. So if someone could clarify this, I would be very happy.

Comment: Try running `convert "test.png -crop 1048x909+436+78 test.png"` directly. You'll get the same error.

Comment: Ahh of course. Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem wasn't with the variables being substituted, but with the whitespace being passed as part of a single argument, instead of separating multiple arguments.

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to write this to work in not just zsh but POSIX-y shells as well, it would be `crop_function() { convert "$1" -crop 1048x909+436+78 "$1"; }` -- no `function` keyword, `()` added after the name, `;` before the closing brace (when a one-liner), all expansions quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your function:

```
function crop_function { convert "$1 -crop 1048x909+436+78 $1" }
```

Thanks to your quotes, this passes a *single* argument to `convert` representing
`$1 -crop 1048x909+436+78 $1`.

Here's an illustration:

```
function test_args { i=1; for arg in "$@"; do echo "$((i++)): $arg"; done; }
function test_crop_1 { test_args "$1 -crop 1048x909+436+78 $1"; }
function test_crop_2 { test_args "$1" -crop "1048x909+436+78" "$1"; }
```

Run as:

```
$ test_args one two three "four five"
1: one
2: two
3: three
4: four five

$ test_crop_1 one two
1: one -crop 1048x909+436+78 one

$ test_crop_2 one two
1: one
2: -crop
3: 1048x909+436+78
4: one
```

Now that we've diagnosed the issue, we can fix the function:

```
function crop_function { convert "$1" -crop "1048x909+436+78" "$1"; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation!